# Нужна ли запятая после слова "хотя"

Tags: пунктуация

Хотя тема была несложной («Житие Александра Невского»), я освежила свои знания и о Левонском ордене.

Comment: Орден Л**и**вонский

Answer (score 2):

Да ни за что! Придаточное, начинающееся с союза "хотя", закрывается после скобок: пошло главное в этом СПП (придаточном уступки).

Comment: Galina Avanesova, периодически возвращаюсь к Вашему ответу, пытаюсь понять его, но... По-моему, в части, идущей после двоеточия, не хватает каких-то слов.

Comment: Это у меня нечаянная инверсия! После двоеточия пошло-началось главное предложение, а дальше я поясняю (списано с учебника, сами мы, как известно, сугубый практик),  в скобках - название такого СПП. Мне никогда не понять смысла этих названий, если их тщательное изучение никого не ведёт к грамотному письму.